# Minimal `_app.js` replacement without changing base behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

According to next.js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-app), if you want to customize `<App>`, you have to create a `pages/_app.js` page, then put your modifications inside.

Still, in their example there is some code, and I don't know what's its purpose:

```
import React from 'react'
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'

export default class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return { pageProps }
  }

  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

    return (
      <Container>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

**Is this the minimal form? Does this example changes the initial behavior?**

In other words, is this code sufficient to extends the original app:

```
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'

export default class MyApp extends App {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you have there won't change anything and is the minimum to extend App (I've tested this).

I think the reason they've included the overridden `getInitialProps` and `render` methods in the documentation is because these are likely the places that you'd want to add customizations to and the code in these is needed if you are overriding them.

For example, if you override `getInitialProps` but don't return the result of `Component.getInitialProps(ctx)` (in this case Component is the current page component, like `./pages/index.js`) then your page components won't have initial props set.